# solving coupled nonlinear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have defined a table containing 3*3 matrices

```
 a1 =Table[Array[
       Subscript[Subscript[ρ, i], #1, #2][t] &, {3, 3}], {i, 1, 3}]
```

Then I define another 3*3 matrix as

```
Hvac = 2*10^-3/
   2*{{Sin[θ]^2, 0, Cos[θ]*Sin[θ]}, {0, 0, 
     0}, {Cos[θ]*Sin[θ], 0, Cos[θ]^2}} + 
  8*10^-5/2*{{Cos[θ]^2*Sin[θ1]^2, 
     Cos[θ1]*Cos[θ]*Sin[θ], -Cos[θ]*
      Sin[θ1]^2*Sin[θ]}, {Cos[θ1]*Cos[θ]*
      Sin[θ], 
     Cos[θ1]^2, -Cos[θ1]*Sin[θ1]*
      Sin[θ]}, {-Cos[θ]*Sin[θ1]^2*
      Sin[θ], -Cos[θ1]*Sin[θ1]*Sin[θ], 
     Sin[θ]^2*Sin[θ1]^2}}
```

where,

```
θ =11.53*π/180
θ1 =33.83*π/180
```

Now I want to solve the following set of differential equations using the below mentioned initial conditions:

```
ai0 = {{10, 10^-5}, {10^-5, 5}};
Ci = Thread[Flatten[a1[[1]]] == Flatten[ai0]] /. {t -> 3};
aii0 = {{10, 10^-5}, {10^-5, 4}};
Di = Thread[Flatten[a1[[2]]] == Flatten[aii0]] /. {t -> 3};
aiii0 = {{10, 10^-5}, {10^-5, 3}};
Ei = Thread[Flatten[a1[[3]]] == Flatten[aiii0]] /. {t -> 3};
s2 = NDSolve[{ 
   I D[a1[[1]], 
      t] == (Hvac/(10*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(a1[[2]] + a1[[3]])).a1[[1]] - 
     a1[[1]].(Hvac/(10*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(a1[[2]] + a1[[3]])), 
   I D[a1[[2]], 
      t] == (Hvac/(11*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(a1[[1]] + a1[[3]])).a1[[2]] - 
     a1[[2]].(Hvac/(11*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(a1[[1]] + a1[[3]])), 
   I D[a1[[3]], 
      t] == (Hvac/(15*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(a1[[1]] + a1[[2]])).a1[[3]] - 
     a1[[3]].(Hvac/(15*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(a1[[1]] + a1[[2]])), Ci, Di, Ei}, 
  Flatten[{Variables[a1[[1]]], Variables[a1[[2]]], 
    Variables[a1[[3]]]}], {t, 3, 10^4}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 15]
```

But it is showing an error

```
NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument {{{I (Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 1,1]^′)[t],I (Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 1,2]^′)[t],I (Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 1,3]^′)[t]},{I (Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 2,1]^′)[t],I (Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 2,2]^′)[t],I (Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 2,3]^′)[t]},{I (Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 3,1]^′)[t],I (Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 3,2]^′)[t],I (Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 3,3]^′)[t]}}=={{Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 2,1][t] (0.00328665 +Times[<<3>>])+Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 3,1][t] (0.0976865 +Times[<<3>>])-Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 1,2][t] (0.00328665 +Times[<<3>>])-Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 1,3][t] (0.0976865 +Times[<<3>>]),<<1>>,Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 1,3][t] (0.0261894 +Times[<<3>>])+<<8>>},{-Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 2,1][t] (0.0261894 +Times[<<3>>])+<<7>>,-Subscript[Subscript[<<2>>], 2,1][t] (<<22>> +Times[<<1>>])+<<4>>,<<1>>},{<<1>>}},<<3>>}. >>
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: ai0 aii0  and aiii0 don't have the right size

Comment: if you correct for this it works

Comment: yeah it worked. thanx a lot.